# jqGrid conflict dialog edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my project I have a page with a jqgrid and a button to open a jquery dialog within another jqgrid.
Every jqgrid called with different name.

When I try to add data to second jqgrid, the edit form is disable, I can't write in the textbox, but the dropdown menu is clickable, but open and close the accordion in the middle dialog.

**CODE BUTTON:**

```
<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#dialogInsieme").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            modal: true,
            width: ($(document).width() - 300),
            height: ($(document).height())
        });

        $("#openerInsieme").click(function() {
            $("#dialogInsieme").dialog("open");
        });
    });
 ]]>
</script>

<div id="dialogInsieme" title="Insieme">
    <jsp:include page="../insieme/show.jspx" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="openerInsieme">Show Insieme</button>
```

The other jqGrid are standard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved.

I delete this option in the dialog:  `modal: true.`

Now the focus is correctly in the last dialog.